# In Meteor is it possible to flush per row of a table?

Tags: meteor

I am building a Meteor app where I have to display a variable length table of calculation results. The calculations are done in Meteor and displayed in cells of the rows - each cell in the table is a numeric result based on a complex calculation. Finally I want to display a total calculation for each row.

calcresult1  calcresult2  row1sum
calcresult3  calcresult4  row2sum
:
(variable number of rows)

How can I efficiently calculate the row sums reactively from the calcresults on each row?

Can I setup a single session variable, sum to it when rendering the cells in the row, and then flush the total as each rowsum is to be rendered?

Comment: Add a `Tracker.autorun()` and include the variables that changes (your `calcresult`). Each time the variables change, recalculate the `rowSum` variable(s)

Comment: How is this question different from the other one you posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021574/in-meteor-how-can-i-reactively-access-currently-displayed-values

Comment: I'll try this, and see if it reruns the calculation of the calcresults (which I am trying to avoid), and also see if it works for summing the columns (as in my other question), and report my findings

Comment: Hi dayuloli, I  have added more details in the other question. Part of the problem is that I dont know how to access the computed calcresults using the sum autoruns, or sum helpers.

Answer (score 2):

If the rows have the same number of cells each time, you could pass the results from each cell helper to a final helper.

```
<template name="calcTable">
    <table>
        {{#each calcRow}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{calcresult1}}</td>
                <td>{{calcresult2}}</td>
                <td>{{rowsum calcresult1 calcresult2}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</template name="calcTable">
```

-

```
Template.calcTable.helpers({
    calcresult1: function() {
        return result;
    },

    calcresult2: function() {
        return result;
    },

    rowsum: function(calcresult1, calcresult2) {
        return calcresult1 + calcresult2;
    }
});
```

Comment: in your solution does rowsum get the values of calcresult1 and 2 by recalculating them?